# Python deadlock error - Trying to retrieve key value from shelve

Tags: python, cgi

Here is my code where I am updating record in shelve

```
def updateRecord(db, form):
    if not 'key' in form:
        fields = dict.fromkeys(fieldnames, '?')
        fields['key'] = 'Missing key input'
    else:
        key = form['key'].value
        if key in db:
            record = db[key]
        else:
            from person import Person
            record = Person(name='?',age='?')
        for field in fieldnames:
            setattr(record, field, eval(form[field].value))
        db[key] = record
        fields = record.__dict__
        fields['key'] = key
    return fields
```

When i am trying to retrieve the value from shelve i am getting this error

```
>>> import shelve
>>> db = shelve.open('class-shelve')
>>> db['sue'].name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 121, in __getitem__
    f = StringIO(self.dict[key])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bsddb/__init__.py", line 270, in __getitem__
    return _DeadlockWrap(lambda: self.db[key])  # self.db[key]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bsddb/dbutils.py", line 68, in DeadlockWrap
    return function(*_args, **_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bsddb/__init__.py", line 270, in <lambda>
    return _DeadlockWrap(lambda: self.db[key])  # self.db[key]
KeyError: 'sue'
```

any insights whats going on?

Comment: do a print `db` to see the contents of the dictionary. My guess is `sue` would not be a key

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. What does the first code snippet have to do with the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming in the first snippet, that the `db` variable is a 'shelf' object, then, although the line...

```
db[key] = record
```

...will add the new key/value pair to the 'shelf', it won't necessarily flush the contents to disk, so it won't be available to other processes sharing the same 'shelf file'.

You can force the 'shelf file' to be written to disk by adding the line...

```
db.sync()
```

...after adding the new key/value pair, but it can be quite slow when your 'shelf file' gets large, so you may not want to call it too frequently.